# oracle function not displaying results

Tags: oracle, stored-procedures, oracle11g, oracle-sqldeveloper

I am very new to this so it might sound basic, however i want create a function that takes two input parameter , (a primary key and a numeric value) and does a calculation to compare if the input numeric value (v_priceWantToInsert) is greater than maximum value in the column of the table and returns the result as true or false.
here is the code :

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION PRICE_CHECK(v_productID IN VARCHAR2, v_priceWantToInsert in NUMBER)
RETURN VARCHAR2
IS
   RETURN BOOLEAN AS
    v_Bool BOOLEAN;
    v_MAXPRICE NUMBER;  
BEGIN
   SELECT
    MAX(B.BIDPRICE) INTO v_MAXPRICE
    FROM
        PRICEBID B
    WHERE B.PRODUCTID = v_productID;
    IF (v_MAXPRICE > v_priceWantToInsert) THEN
        v_Bool := FALSE;
    ELSE
        v_Bool := TRUE;
    END IF;
END PRICE_CHECK;



DECLARE
    var1 VARCHAR2(100);
BEGIN
     var1 := case when PRICE_CHECK('P00001',45) then 'true' else 'false' end;
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('It is: ' || var1);
END;
```

however my code is showing an error that object is invalid AND Usually a PL/SQL compilation error.I am open to any solution as long as it gives me a true or false value.

Answer (score 0):

There are some moments I see in the code:

1. Missing string's length in DECLARE part. Oracle requires to specify variable's length when it is a "stringy" type, like VARCHAR or CHAR. Limit is 32767:

   ```
    var1 VARCHAR2(100); -- might be up to 32767
   ```
2. In the function you are using variable v_MAXPRICE which is not defined. It must be done between IS and BEGIN parts of the function's defintion. I think this is how it should look like:

   ```
    IS
      v_MAXPRICE number;
    BEGIN
   ```
3. There is another moment you have in your code after you've updated the question

   ```
    RETURN VARCHAR2
    IS
       RETURN BOOLEAN AS
        v_Bool BOOLEAN;
        v_MAXPRICE NUMBER;
   ```

Having 2 returns is wrong, replace it with

```
       RETURN BOOLEAN
       IS
        v_Bool BOOLEAN;
        v_MAXPRICE NUMBER;
```

and since it is a function and has to return something you need to add

```
return v_bool
```

after "end if"

4. I thnk the last part is the anonimous block

first of all, your function returns boolean into var1 which is defined as a varchar2. This is wrong as Oracle can't convert booleans to string and it needs help with that.

try that out:

```
    var1 := case when PRICE_CHECK('P00001',45) then 'true' else 'false' end;
```

Comment: Changed this , yet got an error : PLS-00905: object  user.PRICE_CHECK is invalid.

Comment: What dev-tool do you use? Is it just sqlplus?

Comment: I use sqldeveloper, it is not really friendly to obtain errors i must say but thats my school project and i cannot change it. I have updated my code above with what i am trying now .

Comment: @pun_intended check the updated answer please

Comment: Hey , it still remained the same . These are the errors : 
06550. 00000 -  "line %s, column %s:\n%s"
*Cause:    Usually a PL/SQL compilation error.
*Action:

Comment: @pun_intended check the updated answer again please

Comment: Hey, it still isnt working :/ I put the code in the last block and it is still the same issue. I am pretty open to any other idea of creating this function block since i think function has some issue itself. I just want to get done with this requirement.

Comment: @pun_intended update the question with what you have. Let's see

Comment: @pun_intended and what is the error now? I mean what does compiler say?